# DropBox API returns "ASyncTask #1 java.lang.RuntimeException" in Android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am currently trying to implement DropBox into my Android App. I have added the client jar file for android and when I try to login to my development dropbox account it keeps on force closing my app.

Below is the code I am using where it is going wrong

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.dropbox.client.DropboxAPI;

public class LoginASyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    private static final String TAG =  "LoginASyncTask";

    String mUser;
    String mPassword;
    String mErrorMessage = "";
    DropBoxLogin mDropBoxLogin;
    DropboxAPI.Config mConfig;
    DropboxAPI.Account mAccount;

    public LoginASyncTask(DropBoxLogin act, String user, String password, DropboxAPI.Config config)
    {
        super();
        mDropBoxLogin = act;
        mUser = user;
        mPassword = password;
        mConfig = config;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void...params)
    {
        try
        {
            DropboxAPI api = mDropBoxLogin.getAPI();

            int success = DropboxAPI.STATUS_NONE;
            if (!api.isAuthenticated())
            {
                                //Going wrong on this line
                mConfig = api.authenticate(mConfig, mUser, mPassword);
                mDropBoxLogin.setConfig(mConfig);

                success = mConfig.authStatus;

                if (success != DropboxAPI.STATUS_SUCCESS)
                {
                    return success;
                }
            }
            mAccount = api.accountInfo();

            if (!mAccount.isError())
            {
                return DropboxAPI.STATUS_SUCCESS;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Account Info Error: " + mAccount.httpCode + " " + mAccount.httpReason);
                return DropboxAPI.STATUS_FAILURE;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error in loggin in", e);
            return DropboxAPI.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
    {
        if (result == DropboxAPI.STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (mConfig != null && mConfig.authStatus == DropboxAPI.STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                mDropBoxLogin.storeKeys(mConfig.accessTokenKey, mConfig.accessTokenSecret);
                mDropBoxLogin.setLoggedIn(true);
                mDropBoxLogin.showToast("Logged into dropbox");
            }
            if (mAccount != null)
            {
                mDropBoxLogin.displayAccountInfo(mAccount);
            }
            else
            {
                if (result == DropboxAPI.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR)
                {
                    mDropBoxLogin.showToast("Network Error: " + mConfig.authDetail);
                }
                else
                {
                    mDropBoxLogin.showToast("Unsuccessful Login");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps on coming up with the stack trace error in the logcat as follows

> FATAL Exception: ASyncTask #1
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

### Edit

Found out by @Kannan Goundan that in the exception it is being caused by:

> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oath.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer

I can not figure out what this means or how I can fix this problem.

Comment: That `RuntimeException` is probably a wrapper around the real exception.  Does the stack trace include a "Caused by" line?  If not, try catching the `RuntimeException` and calling `getCause()` to get the real exception.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added an edit to the question that provides information about the runtime exception caused by line.

Comment: sorry I can't give an answer but the scribe-java oauth library has built in DropBox support https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. I didn't import one of the jar files (signpost-core) into the project build path. Once this was imported it then worked fine.